# Abrir y modificar un archivo de excel desde un datagridview c#

Tags: c#

Lo que debo de hacer es abrir mediante un openfiledialog un documento de excel el cual debo mostrarlo en un datagridview (hasta este momento si logro hacerlo). Luego de eso el datagridview debe de ser modificable (aún logro hacerlo) y finalmente en un botón debe de guardar el contenido nuevo de grid en el mismo documento y la misma hoja. Tienen alguna idea de como hacerlo?

```
using (OpenFileDialog ofd = new OpenFileDialog() { Filter = "Excel Workbook 97-2003|*.xls|Excel Workbook|*.xlsx", ValidateNames = true })
            {
                // ofd.Filter = "Excel Workbook|*.xls;*.xlsx;*.xlsm";
                {
                    if (ofd.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
                    {
                        //Read excel file
                        ruta2 = "";
                        FileStream fs = File.Open(ofd.FileName, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
                        ofd.FileName = ruta2;
                        IExcelDataReader reader;
                        if (ofd.FilterIndex == 1)
                        {
                            reader = ExcelReaderFactory.CreateBinaryReader(fs);
                        }
                        else


                            reader = ExcelReaderFactory.CreateOpenXmlReader(fs);

                        reader.IsFirstRowAsColumnNames = true;
                        result = reader.AsDataSet();
                        comboBox1.Items.Clear();
                        //Add sheet to combobox
                        foreach (DataTable dt in result.Tables)
                            comboBox1.Items.Add(dt.TableName);
                        reader.Close();
                    }
                }
            }
```

Comment: Androso. Muéstranos tu código por favor. Necesitamos ver qué tienes escrito y cuál es el error que te arroja para poder ayudarte.

Comment: Es que no llevo nada de cogido en el boton de modificar porque la verdad no tengo idea de como :( solamente el boton que abre y muestra el documento. Aún así lo pondré gracias

Comment: que libreria usas para leer el excel? porque veo alli un `ExcelReaderFactory` pero de donde sale

Comment: Esta linea `ofd.FileName = ruta2;` esta de mas, puede quitarla, ya que instancias el OpenFileDialog nuevamente para abrir otro archivo